# Need a boolean check every frame(update call).But the function called from that boolean check should be called only once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am working on a project using a webcam.If i go out-of-screen(view of the camera) a timer starts which track the time i am out of view and if it goes above a certain max value my game gets paused.
Similarly for the In-screen view(inside camera view), timer starts and after max value it resumes the game.

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (InFrontOfScreen()) //This is a condition 
        {
            isInFront = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            isInFront = false;
        }
        InView();
        Pausing();
    }

    private void Pausing()
    {
        if (isPaused)
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        else
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }

    private void InView()
    {
        if (isInFront)
        {
            inViewTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
            if (inViewTime >= maxInViewTime)
            {
                isPaused = false;
                
                
            }
            outOfViewTime = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            outOfViewTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
            if (outOfViewTime >= maxOutOfViewTime)
            {
                isPaused = true;
               
                
            }
            inViewTime = 0f;
        }
    }
```

Now in another script I have to call functions that depend on whether the game is paused or not.

```
    void Update()
    {
        SwitchCameras();
    }

    private void SwitchCameras()
    {
        if(PauseController.isPaused)
        {
            gameCam.enabled = false;
            mainCam.cullingMask = pausedLayerMask;
        }
        else
        {
            gameCam.enabled = true;
            mainCam.cullingMask = originalLayerMask;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this gameCam.enabled and mainCam should be called only once when the bool isPaused changes.It is being called every frame. I get the answer right but I want it to be called only once and not every frame.Is there a way to acheive this?
Though isPaused can change back and forth the functions should be called once and then again when isPaused changes .
Thank you

Comment: The if-else statement in the first Update method can be replaced by `isInFront = InFrontOfScreen();`. I.e., simply assign the value returned by `InFrontOfScreen()`.

Comment: So. make ispaused a property and in the set. Call an on changed function as required when the current value and the new value arent the same

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you only need to cache the value and when a new update is called just check if the value changed

```cs
// Somewhere have a field that saves previous state
private bool _wasPaused;

void Update()
{
    SwitchCameras();
}

private void SwitchCameras()
{
    if (_wasPaused != PauseController.isPaused)
    {
        if (PauseController.isPaused)
        {
            gameCam.enabled = false;
            mainCam.cullingMask = pausedLayerMask;
        }
        else
        {
            gameCam.enabled = true;
            mainCam.cullingMask = originalLayerMask;
        }
    }
    _wasPaused = PauseController.isPaused;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Was on Christmas holiday.Caching the value does indeed work here.

Comment: Happy to hear that. If this solved your issue, please mark this as an answer for future folks who find this

Comment: Stack overflow is not allowing me currently as i do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a private variable and a property. This way we can check to see when a property changes value, and just process an action when the value changes.

Very quickly, this should be a way to achieve what you’re trying to do:

```cs
private bool _isInFront;
public bool isInFront
{
    get => _isInFront;
    set
    {
        if ( _isInFront == value )
            return;
        _isInFront = value;
        InView();
    }

}

private void Update ()
{
    isInFront = InFrontOfScreen(); //This is a condition 
    Pausing();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't simply caching the value and then checking if it changed better than creating a property and tracking the change in the setter?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that this gameCam.enabled and mainCam should be called only once when the bool isPaused changes

Well in that case (and in general) you should not poll check flags in `Update` at all but rather make your code **reactive event driven** and only react a single time the moment the value actually  is changed.

So in your first script I would add a

```
public event Action<bool> pauseStateChanged;
```

whenever you set the state of `isPaused` also invoke the event accordingly and do the change check already here in the responsible class instead of all listeners having to track it themselves

```
...
// Check makes sure the event is really only called when the state is changed
if(!isPaused)
{
    isPaused = true;
    pauseStateChanged?.Invoke(true);
}
```

and then in the other script(s) attach a listener once which will only be invoked when the event is invoked -> when the state actually changed

```
private void Start()
{
    // start listening to the event
    PauseController.pauseStateChanged += SwitchCameras;

    // initially call the callback once with the current state
    SwitchCameras(PauseController.isPaused);
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    // remove the listener once not needed anymore to avoid exceptions
    PauseController.pauseStateChanged -= SwitchCameras;
}

private void SwitchCameras(bool isPaused)
{
    gameCam.enabled = !isPaused;
    // Using a ternary here makes this way easier to read imho
    mainCam.cullingMask = isPaused ? pausedLayerMask : originalLayerMask;
}
```

---

And following this very same principle you could also make the rest of your first script reactive the same way instead of calling things every frame in `Update` I would probably use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and do

```
private Coroutine routine;

void Update()
{     
    var currentIsInFront = InFrontOfScreen();

    // Did state change?
    if(isInFront != currentIsInFront)
    {
        if(routine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(routine);
        }

        isInFront = currentIsInFront;
        routine = StartCoroutine(PauseRoutine);       
    }
}

private IEnumerator PauseRoutine()
{
    var newPausedState = !isInFront;

    if(isPaused != newPausedState)
    {
        var delay = isInFront ? maxInViewTime : maxOutOfViewTime;

        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(delay);

        isPaused = newPausedState;  

        pauseStateChanged?.Invoke(newPausedState);

        Time.timeScale = newPausedState ? 0f : 1f;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a brilliant explanation.Thank you. I didn't knew about Action<>. If i can ask maybe, how did you approach this problem. After reading and searching it on the net I understood that the approach you suggested is like an observer pattern. Did you identify the pattern which can work here or does it just comes with experience. Thank you.

Comment: Experience ;) I've been working with Unity for 6 years now .. and then basically your wording already suggests this pattern - that's why included your cite at the top ;) it basically asks for this exact pattern. Most properties in Unity might cause some extra work so going event driven is best in many cases

Comment: Nice :) The answer really helped me and led me to explore new ideas and concepts.
I don't know how i got this far without knowing about Events. Lol.
Thanks once again though.